# Proof of positive definiteness

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, differential-operators

$Lu = -u'' + c u$ where c is some constant

The question is when it's positive definite in square integrable on $[0; 1]$ with $u(0)=u(1)=0$

$(Lu, u) = \int^1_0 u Lu dx = -u u''+c u^2 dx = \int^1_0 (u')^2 + cu^2 dx$>0$

---

How do I proceed?

I know the answer is $c>-\pi^2$ but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: One option is to use Fourier series/Sturm–Liouville theory.

Comment: Another is [Wirtinger's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions) in an appropriate form.

Comment: @Chappers "second  version" is really the solution, thanks a lot.

Comment: You can also look at the eigenvalues of $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ with the boundary condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L$ be the operator operator $Lu = -u''$ on the domain $\mathcal{D}(L)$ of twice absolutely continuous functions $u$ on $[0,1]$ for which $u(0)=u(1)=0$. Then $L$ a selfadjoint linear operator with a complete orthogonal basis of eigenfunctions $\{ \sin(n\pi x) \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. The spectrum of $L$ consists of the corresponding eigenvalues $\pi^{2}n^{2}$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. Therefore,
$$
              (Lu,u) \ge \pi^{2}(u,u),\;\;\; u \in \mathcal{D}(L),
$$
with equality for some $u \ne 0$ iff $u$ is a constant multiple of $\sin(\pi x)$. Therefore, $L+cI$ is positive definite iff $c > -\pi^{2}$. It is positive, but not positive definite if $c = -\pi^{2}$ because $(L-\pi^{2}I)\sin(\pi x)=0$.

Comment: Yes. Mr Chappers actually provided the link with a solution. Anyway, thank you for your answer!